# Adding a persistent component to _app.js in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sidebar

So I am playing around with my first Nextjs app and am having trouble with adding a persistent sidebar.

I found [Adam Wathan's article](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/) on persistent layouts in nextjs, but it seems like there is a newer pattern that was added recently using the _app.js page. I went to [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) and a few of the github issues around it, but it doesn't looks like there's a lot of documentation around it yet.

So for my example, I have my _app.js file:

```
import '../css/tailwind.css'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";

export default function App({Component, pageProps}){
  return(
    <>
      <Head />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Transition from "../components/Transition";
import Link from 'next/link'

function Sidebar({ children }) {
 const [isSidebarOpen, setIsSidebarOpen] = useState(false);
  const [hideSidebarMenu, setHideSidebarMenu] = useState(true);

  const openSidebar = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(true);
    setHideSidebarMenu(false);
  };

  const closeSidebar = () => {
    setIsSidebarOpen(false);
  };

  const hideSidebar = () => {
    setHideSidebarMenu(true);
  };

  return(
    <div>
      /*sidebar links here*/
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

How do I integrate my sidebar component into this? I've tried adding it next to component and wrapping component and a few other iterations with no luck. Hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @Emile, I added a simple placeholder for the sidebar, but I didn't want to add extra complexity to the post if not needed. I figure the content on the component i want to be persistent (in this case the sidebar) wasn't an issue if I can reference it, but if this is not the case, I can add more info if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is odd. I could have swore I tried this very simple solution before, but something like this was completely sufficient.

This solution will feed in the page that you are on using the children prop in the sidebar.

```
import '../css/tailwind.css'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";

export default function App({Component, pageProps}){
  return(
    <>
      <Head />
      <Sidebar >
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Sidebar>
    </>
  )
}
```

this option will just render the sidebar along with the content

```
import '../css/tailwind.css'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";

export default function App({Component, pageProps}){
  return(
    <>
      <Head />
      <Sidebar />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Good job figuring it out on your own and then coming back to answer your own question! That's what I wanted to see when I asked a for [mcve] because I was wondering how it wasn't working since you were so close and saying you had tried it already!